Augmenting lib.dom.d.ts interface with interface declared in an imported @types package
I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to do some interface declaration merging. There is this interface from lib.dom.d.ts that is automatically imported, and there is the same interface in a @types package that I'm using in my project. I'm trying to merge them, but when I import the one from @types it is actually overwriting the other.

Interface Navigator from lib.dom.d.ts
Import Navigator from the @types package
Expected the interfaces to merge but getting only the @types one

I've gone through the typescript tutorials, and I know how to extend the lib.dom.d.ts Navigator myself. I suppose I can always do that if what I want is not possible:
 // global.d.ts
 interface Navigator {
    properties_from_type: any;
 }

I also know how to extend the interface from the @types package:
import {Navigator} from 'three';

declare module 'three' {
    interface Navigator {
        properties_from_dom: any;
    }
}

But ultimately, I just want to merge the lib.dom.d.ts one with the ones from @types package. Seems like it should be simple right?
